# Lua liblua5.1.so cannot open shared object file

Tags: c, debugging, compilation, linker, lua

So I have a compiled C file in .so format, and am trying to use it from within Lua. The code for the 2 files is:

```
-- luatest.lua:
require("power")

print("Enter a number: ")
local num = tonumber(io.read())

local n = create(num)
square(n)
cube(n)
nprint(n)

// luatest.c compiled to power.so

#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int createStruct(lua_State *L);
static int isquare(lua_State *L);
static int icube(lua_State *L);
static int nprint(lua_State *L);

typedef struct numbers {
    float number;
    float square;
    float cube;
} numbers;

int luaopen_power(lua_State *L){
    lua_register(L, "create", createStruct);
    lua_register(L, "square", isquare);
    lua_register(L,"cube",icube);
    lua_register(L, "nprint", nprint);
    return 0;
}

static int createStruct(lua_State *L){
    // Code here
}

static int isquare(lua_State *L){              
    // Code here
}

static int icube(lua_State *L){              
    // Code here
}

static int nprint(lua_State *L){
    // Code here
}
```

The C code compiles fine. But when I try to do:

```
cd <directory>
lua luatest.lua
```

I get the following error:

```
lua: error loading module 'power' from file './power.so':
liblua5.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
stack traceback:
[C]: ?
[C]: in function 'require'
luatest.lua:3: in main chunk
[C]: ?
```

I'm not sure what's wrong as ./power.so should exist.

I'm getting this error on openSUSE 64bit, but this exact code works fine on OSX.

Any insight into this would be great, I can't seem to find anyone else with this issue anywhere.

Comment: For this to be useful you should add why removing `-llua5.1` solved your problem. Otherwise it wouldn't make any sense -- someone would wonder, you're compiling a C lua module, why wouldn't you want to link against the lua library?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it. It'll mark the question as answered, and it'll make it easier for people tackling the same problem to find your solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I was compiling it using gcc with the -l[1] flag at lua5.1. Remove this and it will work!
>
> -l library
>              Search the library named library when linking.

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o <output file name> -I<path to lua include directory> <input file name>
```